# Linking an external JS library and getting XMLHttpRequest error

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I need to use a JavaScript library and have it referenced as such:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.authorize.net/v1/Accept.js"></script>
```

However I get an error that states:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://js.authorize.net/v1/AcceptCore.js.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I've researched this issue and tried various bits of code and ideas, but it hasn't worked for me. I am using ASP.NET, webforms, and c#. I've tried adding various code to my web.config, such as

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

and

```
   <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
          </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
      </system.webServer>
```

I also tried the recommendation of installing Cors, but I am using framework 4.0. Cors requires 5.0 and failed to install.

Comment: Either you can just save that js locally or you have to fix CORS settings from where your trying to access this js

Comment: @IndraUprade I will not be able to save it locally. It is part of an Authorize.Net secure payment library that will need to consistently be updated and watched for PCI compliance. How can I fix the cors settings, specifically? I have been trying and haven't had luck.

Comment: This is odd.  There is no same-origin protection applied to straight script tags, so I think the error you show is not actually coming from your script tag.

Comment: @jfriend00: The script the OP is loading is turning around and loading another script, looks like some kind of authorization thing. That's why the OP is getting an XHR error on a script tag.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - OK, I didn't see the error message was referring to a slight differently named script.

Comment: @jfriend00: Yeah, I was confused by why he/she would get that error, so I went and looked at the script. Once you deobfuscate it slightly, you can see what's going on. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script you're loading is just turning right around and using `XMLHttpRequest` to load another one (also from js.authorize.net); that request is being denied because your page's origin isn't allowed access. Looks like some kind of authorization thing to keep their JS from being downloaded on unauthorized origins.

**Nothing** you do on your end changes the CORS rules at the js.authorize.net end. It's that server, js.authorize.net, that has to allow your origin to do the request.

You'll need to work with the people behind js.authorize.net in order to get access.

Comment: Ah! Okay, this makes sense. I was getting frustrated with my attempts. lol Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This may have been added since the original post, but for others to know, Authorize.net addresses this on the Accept.js page on their site.
Link: https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html

> NOTE: If you are debugging, you may see an XMLHttpRequest error in the JS console. This is because our core processing library cannot be called directly, and this is an expected security warning.

Everything still works despite the error.